# My random number generator is not working, have tried looking at other questions, no resolve

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package Review_Randomnum;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class RandomNum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a minimum value: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a maximum value: ");
        int second = input.nextInt();
        int number = ((int)(Math.random()) * ((second - first)) + first);
        System.out.println(number);


    }

}
```

So I've checked numerous answers on this website, and to no avail, I don't get any errors, I just get the minimum value printed. I don't know how to get the program to produce a random integer between the two values input

Answer (score 5):

Your random number is being truncated to 0 in the following expression:

```
((int)(Math.random())
```

The reason for this is that `Math.random()` returns a *double* greater than or equal to `0` and less than `1`, which when cast to an `int` will be *truncated* to `0` (see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) for more information).

Instead, compute your desired number first as a `double`, and then cast back to an `int`:

```
int number = (int)(Math.random() *(second - first) + first);
```

Comment: A better solution would be to use [`Random.nextInt(int n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29): `Random rnd = new Random(); int number = rnd.nextInt(second - first + 1) + first;`

Comment: Also, you missed the `+ 1`. Without it, you'll never get the "maximum value", i.e. value of `second`.